# How to load all rows in codeigniter-base-model? REST api

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to load all rows for my REST API through Postman.

I am using codeigniter-base-model MY_Model.php.

https://github.com/jamierumbelow/codeigniter-base-model

This is how my code currently looks like both in my controller/model:

**Controller(api_news.php)**:

```
class Api_News extends REST_Controller {

function __construct() 
{
    parent::__construct();
}

function index_get()
{
    $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $this->load->model('News_model');
    $news = $this->News_model->get_by(array('id' => $id));

    if(isset($news['id'])) {
        $this->response(array(
            'message' => 'success', 
            'status' => 'true', 
            'data' => $news));
    } else {
        $this->response(array(
            'message' => 'unsuccess', 
            'status' => 'false'));
    }
}
}
```

**Model(news_model.php)**:

```
class News_model extends MY_Model{

protected $_table = 'news';
protected $primary_key = 'id';
protected $return_type = 'array';

}
```

At the moment if I access:

**localhost/my_api/api_news/id/1, 2, 3, etc...**

I can access any record by its individual ID and it shows up which is great.

BUT I also want to be able to see all rows by doing this:

**localhost/my_api/api_news/id/**

and have all rows showing at once.

But I am not sure how to do this...and am getting an unsuccess/false if I try.

Can you please show me how? I am new to PHP in general and I appreciate any help.

Thank you so much!!

Comment: Would you like to show us these tries and why they were unsuccessful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make some changes in your Controller function as below -

```
function index_get(){
    $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $this->load->model('News_model');

    // pass $id to model 
    $news = $this->News_model->get_by( $id );

    if( !empty( $news ) ) {
        $this->response(array(
            'message' => 'success', 
            'status' => 'true', 
            'data' => $news));
    } else {
        $this->response(array(
            'message' => 'unsuccess', 
            'status' => 'false'));
    }
```

}

And in your model make id parameter optional and then check that if id is passed get data based on id otherwise return all data as below -

```
// $id variable is optional here
function get_by( $id = '' ) {

    if ( $id == '' ) {
        $news = $this->db->get( 'news' );
    }
    else {
        $news = $this->db->get_where( 'news', array( 'id' => $id ) );
    }

    // return data to controller
    return $news->result();

}
```

So if you enter id in API then data will be based on that id otherwise all data will be returned.

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you. Kindly accept this answer so that other users get to know that this solution works.